# Resources to switch between alphabets

Tags: orthography, tools

Is there a tool I could use, like a macro or something, that changes a Cyrillic orthography to IPA (and vice-versa) according to my specifications? (it's for a non-Slavic minority language).

I'm not a programmer, but this strikes me as a simple thing.

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably not a simple thing because of all kinds of non-uniqueness involved. You will see it while writing up the specifications. As a programming language, I suggest python, perl, or sed.

Comment: Yes, there are some complications, but I think they can be easily addressed. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: IPA does not include symbols for many Russian sound, for instance, for the vowel я. It is English-centric. Also it is anatomy-based and does not reflect how sounds are sounded, only how they are pronounced.

Comment: Cyrillic is used for many languages. It can't be assumed to be phonemic every time. (Is it even vaguely phonemic?)

Comment: The mapping I use isn't a 1-to-1 mapping for every Cyrillic language! It works only for one language, which isn't even Slavic. Anyway, the question is about a resource to switch between alphabets not on the mapping!

Comment: @Teusz What to you mean by "switching" then? Using a different keyboard or converting text from one alphabet into the other? The latter requires correct mapping.

Comment: I mean mapping, as in my response below. Again, I'm not doing this for ALL Cyrillic languages, but just for one non-Slavic language that uses a Cyrillic alphabet and with whose phonology I am already familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your additional comments I see that you want to have some LaTeX input that can be rendered in two ways: Cyrillic orthography and IPA. I suggest the following approach: Design some LaTeX macros, one Macro for each possible pair (Cyrillic letter(s), IPA representation). There will be easy cases and complicated ones. Then use some switches to the macros to render them in the fashion you want to have them.

For more in-depth advice on designing the LaTeX macros, ask a question of the TeX stackexchange http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

As said by the commenters, the task is not that straightforward because there is no 1:1 correspondence between Cyrillic and the IPA symbols depicting the corresponding sounds.
This holds both for the usage of Cyrillic as a writing system for various language and even the translation of Cyrillic to IPA within one language, because most, if not all alphabetical systems are not fully phonetic.
And even within IPA itself there are problems, such as phonological varieties or the IPA inventar not being perfectly applicable for the Russian language (see comments), you'd have to decide on your own whether IPA suits your needs.

With a little effort, you could either build a converter based on phonological rules (but then specific to a language, not to an alphabet) - this would be linguistically better motivated and fully productive, thus stable against rare words and forms - or one that retrieves the IPA transcription from an external resource, e.g. Wiktionary (this would be easier to implement without linguistic knowledge, but is dependent on the Wiki coverage for the language you are concerned about, which might cause difficulties with compunds, inflected forms or rare words, although I find it in general a great resource).
Both, however, requires some programming skills. You could check whether there is something similar or at least parts of it floating around on the internet - I am sure there is at least someone who has attempted to crawl and process Wiktionary, maybe there is even something for the language you are interested in that might point in the right direction.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to make a converted IPA<>Cyrillic for every Slavic language, just for a particular one (not even a Slavic language), in which case the mapping is easily established. There are no online tools for this particular minority language... I'm really just looking to make my own, where if I input the word [ja] I get the output [Я] and vice-versa.

Comment: If the mapping is as easy is you say, then it should not be too difficult to write your own tool based on phonological rules. However, I could imagine that the direction IPA -> Cyrillic is a bit more tricky than the other way round.

Comment: Good point real IPA>Cyrillic. But so long as it's only used for this one language, should be fine. Anyway, I want to write my own tool, indeed. But where do I start? How do I do that? Find+Replace in LaTeX is driving me crazy since in my description I need a orthographic tier and linguistic transcription, I'm always switching between the two systems. Thanks

Comment: If the linguistics side is not too heavy (rather simple phonological mapping), you might get more answers on Stackoverflow then as far as the algorithm part is concerned. I think that a simple Python script or something should do the job, but that depends on how much effort you are willing to spend to master this (if you say you're not a programmer).